# Trying to wrap my head around exec and vim-escaping

Tags: vimscript

I have this

```
let command = "execute printf(\"echo '%s'\", 'foo')"
```

It works fine.

```
execute command
```

However, if I prep it for INSERT-mode escaping.

```
let command = "execute <ESC> printf(\"echo '%s'\", 'foo') <CR>"

imap . command
```

In insert mode, I hit `.` VIM blows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Mappings are basically the same as typing the right-hand side when they are executed. This means that when you type `.`, it's the same as if you typed

`execute`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`printf(\"echo '%s'\", 'foo')`<kbd>Esc</kbd>

So what you'll get is the word `execute` followed by whatever normal-mode commands come after the `<ESC>`, which obviously isn't what you're after.

What you *actually* want to do is go to command line mode before typing `execute`. You can do so by using `<C-o>` to get out of insert mode, and then `:` to get into command line mode.

You're going to have problems with echoing to the command line because when you return to insert mode it will clear out the command line, but this technically works:

```
let command = "<C-o>:execute printf(\"echom '%s'\", 'foo')<CR>"
exe "imap . " . command
```

You can tell it works because if you do `:mess` after pressing `.` in insert mode you'll see your message.

One workaround is to set the `cmdheight` larger than one. This way you'll still be able to see a few lines back even after insert mode has "pushed" the command line back with the message:

`-- INSERT --`

See [`:help i_CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-O) and [`:help 'cmdheight'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cmdheight%27) for more info.

Comment: I want it to actually output "foo" in the status bar (like `echo foo`) in insert mode when `.` is typed. Your command inserts `echo 'foo'` in text rather than outputting "foo"

Comment: Ah, Ok sorry I'll update. I think you're just missing a `:`.